# I get this error when copying some files with rsync: "rysnc: read errors mapping “…” input/output error" - I can open and watch the file in VLC

Tags: rsync, cp, ntfs

I am using rsync to clone hundreds of video files to another hard drive. There were 3 files which had the exact error as below:

```
rsync: read errors mapping "/var/run/importcopy/tmpdir/dev/da1s1/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2055_Rob.mp4": Input/output error (5)
```

Using VLC I can open the file and play it fine so I know the file is ok. The permissions and ownership of the file are the same as other files that have copied without issue.

```
$ ls -lah /media/robby/My\ Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw\ footage/MVI_205*_Rob.mp4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby  79M Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2051_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby  14M Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2052_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 376M Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2053_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 151M Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2054_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 2.6G Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2055_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 2.5G Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2056_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 1.5G Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2057_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 1.9G Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2058_Rob.mp4'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 robby robby 1.9G Dec  9  2019 '/media/robby/My Passport/Videos/2019/12-December/09-Packing-Video/Raw footage/MVI_2059_Rob.mp4'
```

Comment: Check for broken file system or broken disk.

Comment: I have tried that. what is unusual is if I copy it using regular copy function in the file browser it can copy. But then I still can't rsync from the new copy either.